# JSON.NET: How to insert an existing JSON into the middle of another?

Tags: .net, json.net

Is there any easy way to insert an existing JSON file into the middle of another?

I have seen others asking how to merge them but I think my problem is unique, I can't seem to find any info on it.

### Edit

Here is first JSON.

```
{
   Name: "test1",
   Items: {
       Name: "test1items"
   }
}
```

I need to insert a second JSON (it's valid json) into a new property called "data" on the first json, the data property you don't see as it doesn't exist, it's below Items. Like so

```
{
   Name: "test1",
   Items: {
       Name: "test1items",
       Data: ........
   }
}
```

So the idea is to use some sort of reader on the first json and find Items.Name and add a new property "Data" and merge in the second JSON.

I haven't included the second JSON as it really shouldn't matter, it's a valid json string.

I have everything in strings so I can parse them etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string json1 = @"
    {
        Name: ""test1"",
        Items: {
            Name: ""test1items""
        }
    }";
string json2 = @"
    {
        ""SomeField"": ""SomeData""
    }";

var obj1 = JObject.Parse(json1);
var obj2 = JObject.Parse(json2);


obj1["Items"]["Data"] = obj2;

var newJson = obj1.ToString();
```

**And the output:**

```
{
  "Name": "test1",
  "Items": {
    "Name": "test1items",
    "Data": {
      "SomeField": "SomeData"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked great!, I was thinking and may have to insert more than one  object. So i tried the following... obj1["Items"]["Datas"]["Data1"] = obj2;   -- Notice the Datas, but it fails, due to the fact it doesn't exist. I presume the fix is easy? So I need to insert a Array Object called Datas and then your original code works. Any ideas?

Comment: Create a JArray and assign it to `obj1["Items"]["Datas"]`

Comment: OR `obj1["Items"]["Datas"] = JToken.FromObject(new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });`